# Probability with uncommon event.

Tags: probability

In a lottery, there are $25$ choosable numbers and you have to choose $15$, but you have to hit all the $15$ numbers, the probability for this is $1$ in $$\binom{25}{15}=3,268,760$$

Let's assume that the Lottery owner gives you one number as a spoiler, the number $1$.

I need to know the probability of choosing $15$ numbers of $25$ hitting all the $15$, but already know one of them.

Thank you!

Comment: The probability is 3,268,760 ???

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it, how could the probability be the same when you know 1 of the numbers that will apper and when you don't know any number?

Comment: I was asking you a question, not providing an answer to this problem. The probability of anything is always between $0$ and $1$!

Comment: @Matthew: He wrote $1$ in $3,268,760$ which means $1/3268760$ and thus a number between $1$ and $0$. I don't think he made a mistake.

Comment: Yes mag, you are correct. I misread this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know one of the numbers, you can remove that of your Lottery. Thus your new "game" is to hit the correct 14 numbers of 24 numbers, which is $1$ in $$\binom{24}{14}=1,961,256.$$ So the probability is $$\frac{1}{1961256}.$$